# Manage Private Posts

Tags: posts, private

I have a public blog but would like to have a section just for my own private notes? What is the easiest way to do this? Is there a way to make an entire category of post private?

Comment: Silly suggestion: just don't publish the private notes? Keep them as drafts?

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps:

1) Create the category for your Private posts, e.g. "Private"

2) Exclude the "Private" category from your main Loop

3) Output the "Private" category using a custom template file, e.g. `category-private.php`

4) Wrap the Loop in `category-private.php` in an `if ( is_user_logged_in() )` conditional

(This assumes, of course, that you are the only user of your site. You will need to modify if you have additional users.)

EDITED TO ADD:

5) Wrap the Loop in `single.php` in an `if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! is_category( 'private' ) ) conditional.

6) Add an `exclude=#' argument, where`#`is the Category ID of the "Private" Category, to any call to`wp_list_categories()`.

Comment: Would this exclude 'Private' from showing up in any tag cloud or category cloud or list?

Comment: Hmm... probably not. You would need to add an `exclude` argument to `wp_list_categories()` if it appears anywhere.

Comment: I added a couple of other steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Private Suite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-suite/)

> "Allows you to choose who can read private content and offers better control of privacy features."

Answer (score 0):

I have been a long time user of the [Wordpress CAPA plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capa/), wich does exactly what I think you are looking for.